# Asynchronous unit tests with .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, unit-testing, asynchronous, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0

I have a fairly standard set of unit tests.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task MyClass_DoesStuff()
    {
        //...
        await foo;
    }
}
```

This was all working fine, but then I needed to downgrade to .NET 4.0. I made the necessary package installations and got everything building. However, now my unit tests no-longer work. Instead, I get these errors:

> UTA007: Method MyClass_DoesStuff defined in class MyTestClass does not have correct signature. Test method marked with the [TestMethod] attribute must be non-static, public, return-type as void  and should not take any parameter. Example: public void Test.Class1.Test(). Additionally, return-type must be Task if you are running async unit tests. Example: public async Task Test.Class1.Test2()

Perhaps the test runner does not recognize `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` for .NET 4.0? I installed `Microsoft Async`, `Microsoft BCL Build Components`, and `Microsoft BCL Portability Pack` from NuGet.

Is there a way for me to get asynchronous unit testing working for .NET 4.0?

**Edit**:

The "duplicate" this was flagged as ([TestMethod: async Task TestSth() does not work with .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458371/testmethod-async-task-teststh-does-not-work-with-net-4-0)) was for the test not showing up in test explorer, whereas in my case I got the error as I posted. Not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TestMethod: async Task TestSth() does not work with .NET 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458371/testmethod-async-task-teststh-does-not-work-with-net-4-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to make your unit test project target .NET 4.5. That way, MSTest will support asynchronous unit tests natively.

Comment: fixing the problem is better than suggesting a new way altogether, you must consider some maybe limited in the amount change they can make and that is no easy, simple change with huge huge projects

Comment: @AltF4_: Changing the target framework *only for the unit test project(s)* should be quite fast even for large projects. It's literally right-click, properties, change framework, save.

Answer (score 3):

`async` and `await` were introduced in .NET 4.5, so you won't be able to use that syntax in .NET 4.0. However, as I recall, `Task`s were introduced in .NET 4.0, so you could probably accomplish your task using `Task` directly.

```
[TestMethod]
public Task MyClass_DoesStuff()
{
    Task<Foo> foo = GetSomethingAsync();
    var result = foo.Result;
}
```

Comment: The `Microsoft Async` NuGet package adds language support for `async` and `await` to .NET 4.0.

Comment: @Jacob: Did you have that Nuget package added to your *test* project?

Comment: Yes, I had it added to my test project, but it seems like the VS test runner didn't support that.